# Ajax call to populate form fields django from with a click button return

Tags: django, ajax, forms, field

I would like to fill  my django field form the return of the click button function. The reason of doing that is to allow both manual and the click button options. the click button function collects readings from a serially connected device. how can I use the ajax call for this purpose - appreciate your help.
[a screen shot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRVrh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lu3V.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ReadingNumber = ["First_Reading", "Second_Reading", "Third_Reading", "Fourth_Reading"];
// First Reading button
//for (i = 0; i < ReadingNumber.length; i++) {
 $(function () {
//        text=''
        var button_id = '.Insert_'
        button_id += ReadingNumber[0]
//        console.log(button_id);
          $(button_id).click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/output/get_reading/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
              var field_id = ReadingNumber[0]
                    field_id += '_Field'
//                     console.log(field_id);
              var elem = document.getElementById(field_id);

              htmlString =' <input type=number step=any name="First_Reading" maxlength="200"  required id="id_'
              htmlString += ReadingNumber[0]
              htmlString += '" value='
              htmlString += data + '>'
//              console.log(htmlString);
              elem.innerHTML = htmlString


//                    console.log();
              }
            });
          });

        });
//}
 // Second Reading button
 $(function () {

          $(".Insert_Second_Reading").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
              url: '/output/get_reading/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
              var elem = document.getElementById('Second_Reading_Field');
              htmlString =' <input type=number step=any name="Second_Reading" maxlength="200" required id="id_Second_Reading" value ='
              htmlString += data + '>'
              //              console.log(htmlString);
              elem.innerHTML = htmlString


//                    console.log();
              }
            });
          });

        });


// Third Reading button
 $(function () {

          $(".Insert_Third_Reading").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
              url: '/output/get_reading/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
              var elem = document.getElementById('Third_Reading_Field');
              htmlString =' <input type=number step=any name="Third_Reading" maxlength="200" required id="id_Third_Reading" value ='
              htmlString += data + '>'
//              console.log(htmlString);
              elem.innerHTML = htmlString


//                    console.log();
              }
            });
          });

        });


// Fourth Reading button
 $(function () {

          $(".Insert_Fourth_Reading").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
              url: '/output/get_reading/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
              var elem = document.getElementById('Fourth_Reading_Field');
              htmlString =' <input type=number step=any name="Fourth_Reading" maxlength="200" required id="id_Fourth_Reading" value ='
              htmlString += data + '>'
//              console.log(htmlString);
              elem.innerHTML = htmlString


//                    console.log();
              }
            });
          });

        });
```

Comment: this is what I managed to do. It works but I could not make it in a loop - rather than replicating the function for every single button:(

Comment: Any idea how can I include this kind of ajax calls in a loop?